# How to make a POST request and send data to API using Kotlin in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I am a novice android user, please help me to implement sending a message to the API. I have a POST request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.admin.ragos.net/api/external/prints ' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "body": "text text text"
}'
```

I have a string that I have to send to this address, how do I implement it in my application when I click on the button in the activity?
I've read the tutorials but I can't figure out how to do it for my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For network call in Android, you can use Retrofit and Volley Library.
Both are good and easy to understand.

Some reference:
[Make HTTPS request using Retrofit](https://www.chillcoding.com/android-retrofit-send-http/)